# Has anyone sucessfully gained weight?

Tags: body-weight, body-mass-index-bmi, weight-gain, whey-protein

I have been to many doctors, all of them said "It is your biotype." or "There is nothing wrong with you, but if you want you could take Whey Protein".

I would like to know of people that were considered skinny and successfully gained weight.

Comment: Stack exchange is a question and "correct answer" format. It is not a place to fish for peoples experiences and opinions. If you want to gain weight then eat more.

Comment: This is an interesting question frequently asked. If someone (including the OP) thinks it's not a proper question format, please edit it into a general question, like "Is it possible to gain weight?" or "How to gain weight?" or "Is your body weight determined by a biotype?" or so. There are a lot of misconceptions about this, so it can be a good discussion here.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFmKLHuTarA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** You gain weight by consuming more calories than you spend ([National Heart, Blood and Lung Institute](http://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/educational/wecan/healthy-weight-basics/balance.htm)).

**2.** If you just consume more calories and you do not start with resistance training, you will convert most of the excessive calories into the body fat rather into bigger muscles, so you will appear fatter (skinny fat) and not "bigger," more muscular, stronger or better looking ([Nutrition.gov](https://www.nutrition.gov/weight-management/commonly-asked-questions-faqs)).

**3.** Your maximal muscle mass is genetically determined ([PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4816288/))

> Skeletal muscle is a highly heritable quantitative trait, with
>   heritability estimates ranging 30–85% for muscle strength and 50–80%
>   for lean mass.

You can increase your muscle mass to a certain point with resistance training but not beyond what your genetics allows you.

**4.** According to [European Food Safety Authority (EFSA)](http://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/efsajournal/pub/1818.htm) ([the content available only here](https://www.scribd.com/document/99695732/EFSA-Health-Claims-Related-to-Whey-Protein-and-Increase-in-Satiety)), there is no cause-effect relationship between whey protein consumption and muscle mass gain, strength or endurance.